# need Test-MigrationServerAvailability

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

Need `Test-MigrationServerAvailability`

The following reference it but never say where to download it

http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/help/preview?AssetId=HA102908370&lcid=1033&NS=O365PROADMIN&Version=15&CTT=5&origin=HA103169067
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874015(v=exchg.150).aspx

```
PS C:\Users\user> Test-MigrationServerAvailability
Test-MigrationServerAvailability : The term 'Test-MigrationServerAvailability' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-MigrationServerAvailability
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-MigrationServerAvailability:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bing instead of Google the answer was readily available.

http://www.wadeware.net/it-infrastructure/migrating-from-third-party-providers-to-office-365-imap4-example-2/

Comment: this is now a dead link

Answer (score 0):

You must be connected to an Exchange server.

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RoquiredVersion 2.0.3
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserprincipalName admin@company.com -showprogress $ True
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```